# jQuery animate background position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-position

I can't seem to get this working.

```
$('#product_family_options_dd').animate({
  height: '300px',
  width: '900px',
  backgroundPosition: '-20px 0px',          
},
```

The height and width animate but not the background.

Comment: just wondering should `backgroundPosition` be `background-position` maybe also `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` could be set?

Comment: I tried backgroun-position-x/y and it seemed to work as expected in Chrome10, but not in FF3 (didn't test in any other browsers)

Answer (score 95):

You don't need to use the background animate plugin if you just use separate values like this:

```
$('.pop').animate({
  'background-position-x': '10%',
  'background-position-y': '20%'
}, 10000, 'linear');
```

Comment: this one works in ff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518834/jquery-animate-background-position-firefox

Comment: Mozilla removed support for background-position-x and background-position-y in FF3, stating it was not in the HTML spec, so this no longer works.

Comment: DON'T USE THIS ANSWER - even if it has the highest vote count.
It does not work in Firefox as FF does not provide the background-position-x/y properties.

Answer (score 40):

I guess it might be because it is expecting a single value?

taken from the [animate page on jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/animate/):

### Animation Properties and Values

All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality. (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be.) Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

Comment: That's completely right and you'll have to add a CSS hook to make background-position usable with animate() and single values on alle browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14218768/1062304

Comment: This was spot on, and just to clarify for anyone finding this as I did, specify `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` as separate values.  Don't just use `background-position`.

Answer (score 35):

Since jQuery doesn't support this out of the box, the best solution I have come across so far is to define your own [CSS hooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) in jQuery. Essentially, this means to define custom methods to get and set CSS values which also works with jQuery.animate().

There is already a very handy implementation for this on github:
https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js

With this plugin in place, you can do something like this:

```
$('#demo1').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      backgroundPositionX: '100%',
      backgroundPositionY: '100%'
    });
  },
  function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      backgroundPositionX: '105%',
      backgroundPositionY: '105%'
    });
  }
);
```

For me, this worked on all browsers tested so far including IE6+.

I did put a quick [demo](http://marcloehe.de/demos/jquery-animatebg/) online a while ago and you can rip it apart if you need further guidance.

Comment: This helped me make a custom lightswitch style toggle skin for checkboxes. Simple and clean.

Answer (score 9):

jQuery's animate function is not exclusively usable for directly animating properties of DOM-objects. You can also tween variables and use the step function to get the variables for every step of the tween.

For example, to animate a background-position from background-position(0px 0px) to background-position(100px 500px) you can do this:

```
$({temporary_x: 0, temporary_y: 0}).animate({temporary_x: 100, temporary_y: 500}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function() {
        var position = Math.round(this.temporary_x) + "px " + Math.round(this.temporary_y) + "px";
        $("#your_div").css("background-position",  position);
    }
});
```

Just make sure to not forget the **this.** inside the step function.

Answer (score 5):

In your jQuery code there is a comma after the backgroundPosition portion:

```
backgroundPosition: '-20px 0px',
```

However, when listing the various properties you want to change in the .animate() method (and similar methods), the last argument listed between curly braces should not have a comma after it. I can't say if that's why the background position isn't getting changed, but it is an error and one I'd suggest fixing.

UPDATE: In the limited testing I've done just now, entering purely numerical values (without "px") works for backgroundPosition in the .animate() method. In other words, this works:

```
backgroundPosition: '-20 0'
```

However, this does not:

```
backgroundPosition: '-20px 0'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works because you are animating the first value, for `background-position-x`, if you try this method to animate the `background-position-y` property it won't work. And you can't use `background-position-y` and support Firefox at the same time...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use simple jquery's Animate to do that as it involves 2 values.

To solve it just include [Background Position Plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js) and you can animate Backgrounds at will.

Comment: This is unnecessary -- see my answer

Comment: @nnyby `background-position-y` and `background-position-x` are not supported in Firefox.

Comment: The plugin URL is dead.
A working plugin can be found here: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js
Some info about its usage incl. a demo is available here:
http://www.marcloehe.de/demos/jquery-animatebg/

Answer (score 3):

You can also use math combination "-=" to move background

```
$(this).animate( {backgroundPositionX: "-=20px"} ,500);
```

Answer (score 2):

try `backgroundPosition:"(-20px 0)"`

Just to double check are you referencing this the [background position](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect) plugin?

Example of it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/YMdGT/1/) with the background position plugin.

Comment: plugin link is dead, there is no such plugin on jquery.com anymore

Comment: The plugin URL is dead.
A working plugin can be found here: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js
Some info about its usage incl. a demo is available here:
http://www.marcloehe.de/demos/jquery-animatebg/

Answer (score 2):

You can change the image background position using setInterval method, see demo here: http://jquerydemo.com/demo/animate-background-image.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have a div My_div 250px x 250px, a background image also 250 x 250

css:

```
#My_div {
    background: url("..//img/your_image.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 250px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$("#My_div").mouseenter(function() {
    var x = 250;
    (function animBack() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            if (x-- >= 0) {
                $('#My_div').css({'background-position': '0px '+x+'px'});;
                animBack();
            }
        }, 10);
    })();

});
$("#My_div").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#My_div').css({'background-position': '0px 250px'}); 
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

I hope it help

Answer (score -1):

Using Firefox:
specifying two values: 
Doesn't work with any combination of syntax -- as several pointed out above.  Using Firebug, I get "Error in parsing value for 'background-position'.  Declaration dropped." until the animation ends.

'backgroundPosition': '17.5em'  -- specifiying 1 value:
works in FF and CHrome OPera, SF(Safari) and IE, with a caveat that the 2nd value or y position (vertical) gets set to "center".  From Firebug, the **element's style** gets set to:
style="background-position: 17.5em center;"

Answer (score -3):

```
function getBackgroundPositionX(sel) {
    pos = $(sel).css('backgroundPosition').split(' ');
    return parseFloat(pos[0].substring(0, pos[0].length-2));
}
```

This returns [x] value. 
Length of number has no matter. Could be e.g. 9999 or 0.

Comment: No vote just yet, but I fail to see the relevance of the answer to the question