# Animate two background in a div

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a div with two background like this:

```
<div class="colCenter" style="height: 750px; top: -25px; width: 72%; left: 18%; background-image: url('img/sfondi/portfolio.jpg'), url('img/sfondi/servizi.jpg');background-position: 0px 0px, 0px -1440px;">
</div>
```

if after a click I try to animate it doesn't work why? here is my code:

```
$(".colCenter").on("click", function() {
    $(".colCenter").animate({
          'backgroundPositionY': '1440px 0px'
    }, 1500, 'linear');
});
```

In animate I have already tried: `'background-position': '0 1440px, 0 0px'` and `'backgroundPositionY': '1440px, 0px'`

I'm working in Firefox16 and more than a background in a div is supported

Comment: what is "it doesn't work" ? Do you get any error in the browser console ? check it... please

Comment: no error in firebug, it doesn't move , very strange

Comment: Instead of animating the `background-position`, I would animate the `top` and `left` of some inner div with the desired background. Much easier, and guaranteed to work.

Comment: No because the position is dynamic isn't animated with top/left or bottom.

Comment: Make the position `absolute`. That is the position of the inner div that contains the background image.

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518834/jquery-animate-background-position-firefox

Comment: No I mean make a new div inside the div that should have the image with position absolute, then animate that newly created div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why?

http://api.jquery.com/animate/ states that:

> All animated properties should be animated to a **single numeric
>   value**

Multiple backgrounds require **multiple** numeric values. jQuery doesn't "understand" your requested animation.

## Then, how?

search for a jquery plugin that interprets the animation you want to do.

-or-

depending on *use case*, use CSS3 animations instead of jQuery.

-or-

animate manually with javascript (periodically set background positions, linear interpolation isn't that hard to do)