# Background-image is not working for @-moz-keyframe of css3 in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have just taken a simple image and trying to animate it. It is working fine in google chrome, but image is not showing in case of firefox. 
Here, I am giving you js fiddle link.

```
<body><div class="icon"></div></body>
```

Rest of the code is given in link:
http://jsfiddle.net/vvkkumar06/tA7qw/

Comment: fire fox is not getting that online image url

Comment: same happening with local image.

Answer (score 1):

the answer in the MDN docs.

http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/#background-image

> **background-image**
>
> This is still a little up in the air, with “only gradients” in the
>   current Working Draft, no background-image at all in the current
>   Editor’s Draft, and “Animatable: no” for background-image in CSS
>   Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3 Editor’s Draft. However,
>   support has appeared in Chrome 19 Canary, and this is something that
>   designers want. Until widespread support arrives this can be faked via
>   image sprites and background-position or opacity.'

At this time I have found that nobody actually supports gradients (Chrome 17, FF 12, IE9). Only Chrome supports background-image (that's why it doesn't work in FF for me).

**To Animate Background**

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518834/jquery-animate-background-position-firefox)

Comment: any alternative?... I want to animate background by changing it

Comment: I think you should try to create some sprites and put js SetInterval & keep changing the images but its nasty on the amount of sprites you have to put for smooth transition

Comment: Well, problem is solved, I did it in another way. using only css3

Comment: that's nice you can post your answer so that other people can get help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should shorten your code like this http://jsfiddle.net/DreamBig/tA7qw/4/. I put backgound-image in the div so you don't have to write it again in the keyframes definition like 6 or 10 times.

```
background-image: url('http://www.rotateweb.com/images/WebDesignB1.jpg');
```

I've tested and it runs perfectly in FF.

Comment: But I am trying to use different backgrounds after a part of animation so I can't fix it by declaring in <div>. Here I have only shown one image but I need to change image after 20% , 40% .. and so on.