# Why is this failing to animate?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.overlay-1').css({backgroundPosition:'30% 100%'});

var to;

function infinite(){
to = setTimeout(function(){
$('.overlay-1').animate({backgroundPosition:"30% 2000%"},12000,function(){
    $('.overlay-1').css({backgroundPosition:'30% 100%'});
  infinite();
    });    
  });
}
infinite();


});
```

Why is this failig to animate the background image? It's meant to be an endless scrolling background image, but nothing is moving?

Cheers,
Sam

Comment: Perhaps CSS animations might work in this case too.

Comment: How would one go about looping the CSS animations?

Comment: I'm interested in this too, I'll try to write up a second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need seperate background positions in you animate function, jquery can't handle multiple css arguments like that. Ex:

```
$('.overlay-1').animate({
    'background-position-x': '30%',  
    'background-position-y': '2000%'},12000, function(){});
```

**EDIT**: Just figured this won't work in FF. Try this one for firefox: 
[jquery animate background-position firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518834/jquery-animate-background-position-firefox)

Comment: Thanks. Does the CSS require separate background positions too?

It's early days for my jQuery, I don't suppose you could expand on your answer a little could you?

Cheers,Sam

Comment: I don't think it does because in most browsers the CSS property `background-position` is parsed to the `background-position-x` `background-position-y` properties. Where X is the horizontal axis and Y is the vertical axis. Firefox however doesn't use separate properties for each axis. That's reason why this doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: To be honest, I'd personally go with the CSS animations (see my other answer). It just feels more robust to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 animations. Do note that it isn't supported in all browsers. You can view browser adoption here: http://caniuse.com/css-animation .

For browsers like IE9 you could use a static image instead to gradually decrease user experience for older browsers.

I wrote up a little example of how to animate the background position with CSS, I'm infinitely looping the Google logo as a background image from top to bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/xMMct/

In your case it's up to you to position the background image as such that it appears to be scrolling endlessly.

Css code:

```
.background {
    background-image: url(https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo11w.png);
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: 200px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% -20%;
    animation:bg 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation:bg 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bg
{
   from {background-position: 0% -20%;}
   to {background-position: 0% 120%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg /* Safari and Chrome */
{
   from {background-position: 0% -20%;}
   to {background-position: 0% 120%;}
}
```

Here's another fiddle where the background appears to be scrolling endlessly (do forgive to little skip every 5 seconds, the values aren't perfect) http://jsfiddle.net/xMMct/1/

**Edit**: Better example (no skips) http://jsfiddle.net/xMMct/2/