# Jquery Animation Method on Background

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-animate

Simple question and easy points for a kind soul who helps a novice.

I'm using Wordpress, jQuery is properly loading in the header.

I've got a ul with a 1600x2000px bg-image. I'd like to change the background-position by  -500px to create a sliding effect like an ad board in a shopping mall. If it's the :last-child, instead of -500, it will +1500 (roll back to the top) but I think I can handle the if/else on my own, just having trouble getting .animate() going.

HTML

```
<ul id="indexSlides">
    <li id="messageBox">
    </li>
    <li id="slideA">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </li>
    <li id="slideB">
      <p>Some more Text</p>
    </li>
    <li id="slideC">
      <p>Some different Text</p>
    </li>
    <li id="slideD">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#indexSlides {
    height: 500px;
    background: url('images/slides.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}

ul#indexSlides > li > p {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// function to slide the background of the list

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

setInterval(function() {
    $("#indexSlides").animate({
        top: '-=500',
    } , {
        duration: 1500,
    }
}, 5000),
});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You mind making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a paren, there's an extra comma or 2, and a comma instead of a semi-colon:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   setInterval(function() { 
    $("#indexSlides").animate({
            top: '-=500'
        } , {
            duration: 1500
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

EDIT:
Here's an example using 2 divs: http://jsfiddle.net/fehays/yXLv3/1/

The inner div is the height of the entire background image.  The outer div has a height of one single slide and a overflow:hidden so you only see one.

Comment: I'm seeing the inline style changing the top position in Firebug now, but the bg-image is not moving. Do I need to absolutely position the list?

Comment: No you have to do something else.  I don't believe you can animate the background image position.  I think you need another element "underneath" your ul that contains the background image. Then you can animate that.

Comment: See my edit. That might be an option for you.  Also, the plugin mentioned by @Richard is a good solution.

Comment: So it should work if I wrap the ul in a containing div with fixed height and overflow hidden, make the lis the height of the containing div and have the background images, then animate the top of the ul? EDIT: should have refreshed before asking, your answer 3 mins ago was the answer to this question.

Comment: Technically yes, but when you animate the <ul>, the <li>s will also animate with it and you won't see them after the first move.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to use the [background-positions animation jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect).

Here it is, not working without the plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/pLx2H/

Here it is, working with the plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/pLx2H/1/

See also [jquery animate background position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position).

Comment: I'd prefer not to use a plugin because it seems like it should be a simple task, and there are 4 or animations that I'm going to chain together with callbacks. This is the first one. According to the jQuery .animate() docs, you can use the method I'm trying to implement.

Comment: JQuery doesn't have built-in support for animation of background position, so yes, you do need the plugin.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I think I'll go with @fehays method. I'd like to use sprites to ensure that once the animation begins, all images are loaded.