# Jquery Animate does not work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I created this code for animate background mouseover, but it does not work, only changes  the background for the other but does not show effects when I use function `animate`:

```
$(".b_header").mouseover(function() {

$(this).css("background-image","url(images/bot/head_down.png)");



/*

Also I've tried other effects and nothing 

$(this).css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} );


$(this).animate(
{backgroundPosition:"(-20px -53px)"}, 
{duration:500});
*/

$(this).animate({ opacity: 5 }, 3000);

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery animate background position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position)

Comment: `opacity` goes from `0` (transparent) to `1` (opaque)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**first of all** , make sure you've used *document.ready*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     ......
     $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
});
```

**second** , in your CSS files make sure u set cross-browser **opacity** attribute

```
opacity: 0; /* Chrome 4+, FF2+, Saf3.1+, Opera 9+, IE9, iOS 3.2+, Android 2.1+ */
filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE6-IE8 */
```

**finally** , opacity value range from 0 (hidden) to 1 (opaque) , there's NO 5 value but it'll work fine as if it's 1

and here's a working example => http://jsfiddle.net/abdullahdiaa/PxGwz/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's animate function does not work with CSS properties that take multiple values.  You can usually separately animate each individual value.  So, that would explain why trying to animate both values of **background-position** won't work.

From the [jQuery doc for `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,

For animating **opacity**, it takes values from 0 to 1, not a value of 5 and to see an animation work with opacity, the object would have to start at a different opacity than you are animating to.

Here's a working example of animating opacity: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zCL7S/

Comment: and for animate background-image ? , i want do this but i don´t know if the problem it´s use until function jquery css and for this no work ?

Comment: @Fran - Animate a background-image how?