# jQuery animate background position with x and y position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery animate background position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position)

For a animated hover effect I try to set the background-position in the function animate of jQuery. I set my hover in a sprite image, when I try to set background-position in the function animate, it seems te work just with one param of pixels. When I try to set two (x and y), it doesn't work anymore at all.

What works (it sets 109px 50% in my source code):

```
$('a#twitter').animate({ 
backgroundPosition: '109px',
});
```

What I want but not works (nothing in my source code):

```
$('a#twitter').animate({ 
backgroundPosition: '109px 0px',
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Nicky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('a#twitter').animate({ 
   background-position-x: '109px',
   background-position-y: '0'
});
```

Comment: Works! I just had to put single quotes around the attribute names too! thanks!

Comment: This does not working in FireFox. Since FF does not support `background-position-x` anymore.

Comment: As Siddharth said, this isn't supported in FF or Opera since background-position-{x,y} isn't a spec.