# Animate Background Image Top position - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to animate a background images top position using jquery?  I have tried -

```
 $('#intro1').animate({ background-position: 'top'}, 1000);
```

and

```
 $('#intro1').animate({ background-position: '0, 1600px'}, 1000);
```

But no luck with either - are there any available plugins / methods that anyone can recommend?

Comment: $('#intro1').animate({ background-position: 'top'}, 1000, function() {  }); doesnt work, also tried to animate via pixels in the same way

Comment: Put your code inside your question.

Comment: no you can't,not with jQuery animate! You can write your own or search for additional solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery animate background position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position)

Answer (score 0):

it' possible, try:

```
$("#element").animate({'background-position':'top'}, 1000);
```

and

```
$('#element').animate({
 'background-position-x':'0',
 'background-position-y':'1600px'
 }, 1000);
```

the `-` in javascript array object are not allowed and you have to convert it as string
Good luck