# jQuery background position not animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
var d= $('#menu-top-menu').children();
d.hover(function(){
    var e= $(this).position().left;
    var f= $(this).parent().position().left;
    var g= e-f;
    $('#menu-top-menu').animate({backgroundPosition, g + "px 3px"});
    console.log(g);
});
```

I dont know why it is not animating.
could you give me some clue to solve the problem?
 Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery animate background position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position).

Comment: You could post the html, it will be easier to identify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the properties to animate separately, and also the correct syntax is to separate the key/value of an objects parameters by a `:` not a comma. Try this:

```
var d= $('#menu-top-menu').children();
d.hover(function(){
    var e= $(this).position().left;
    var f= $(this).parent().position().left;
    var g= e-f;
    $('#menu-top-menu').animate({
        'background-position-x': g + 'px', 
        'background-position-y': '3px'
    });
    console.log(g);
});
```

You could also leave out `background-position-y` assuming it never changes, and is set in CSS.

Comment: @architesa check this `$('#menu-top-menu').animate(backgroundPosition:"("+g +"'px' 3px)");`

Comment: @Tushar, did you test that code? It seems to contain an object literal without curly braces, which is a syntax error.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position here you can see it can be done without curly braces

Comment: @Tushar, really? Where? If you're referring to Jonathan Head's and Mark's answers, they only contain partial code.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this ... hope it will work( for help : http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$("#menu-top-menu").animate({
    background-position-x:"20px", 
    background-position-y: "3px"
  },1500);
```